# JavaFX Rotate ImageView

Tags: image, javafx, rotation

I'm trying to rotate an `ImageView` 90 degrees (JavaFX) each time the button is clicked:

```
private void rotate90(ActionEvent e){
    if(currentImage != null){
        imageView.setRotate(90);    
    }
}
```

but my code only rotates `ImageView` once, and after that it just stops.

Comment: Your code example is a bit short: How do you call the method? Why do you check `currentImage` a where is it changed?

Comment: Method is called by button:

Comment: MenuItem rot90 = new MenuItem(bundle.getMessage("rot90"));
        rot90.setOnAction(this::rotate90);

Comment: currentImage is the image displayed in scrollpane

Comment: basically, I'm working on mimic of photoshop, where user should be able to open an image and apply some filters to it, as well as rotating the image

Comment: @V.Savage Have you tried checking if `currentImage` is null?

Answer (score 8):

Initially the value of you rotate property is 0. Once you execute rotate90, you set the property to 90. Each subsequent call does the same.
See the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setRotate-double-)
You can achieve your desired behaviour through a [Rotation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/transform/Rotate.html) or by updating the value:

```
imageView.setRotate(imageView.getRotate() + 90);
```

Comment: How to rotate `Image` not the `ImageView`?

Comment: @FaizanMubasher: You can't: [`Image`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html) is the immutable representation of the pixels. What you can do is create instances of the image in different sizes, but if you want rotation through code you have to do it through the `ImageView` or process the image to create a new one, which is a different question.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code: CW_90 -> ClockWise90 degree.

```
BufferedImage sourceImage;
BufferedImage outputImage;
Scalr.rotate(sourceImage, Scalr.Rotation.CW_90, outputImage);
```

Comment: This is a good example for people who want to only operate on Buffered Images. Id recommend just pulling what you need out of the class below, before creating a new dependency:
https://github.com/rkalla/imgscalr/blob/master/src/main/java/org/imgscalr/Scalr.java